# SVG inline styling

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to size an svg element through css but instead of reducing the image size it cuts the picture in half as if i'm applying the resize to a container element...please check at http://www.vgtest.co.nf/

```
svg#gear {
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   position:fixed;
   left:0%;
   top:50%;
}
```

Comment: the g element (background) is keeping its original size (593 x 593px)..but why?

Comment: you define the wrong SVG ID. you should used `svg#gear`

Comment: i've erased all the styling except on #gear but it still has the same problem--it seems like the path & ground have their original size ...maybe its inline in the svg code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define the height and width property as well for SVG element..

```
svg#gear {
    height: 593px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 593px;
}
```

Also If the viewport and the view box does not have the same aspect ratio (width-to-height ratio), you need to specify `preserveAspectRatio` attribute of the `<svg>` element.

For example in your case.

```
<svg width="593px" height="593px" viewBox="0 0 1700 1700" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
```

Comment: thanks! i'm playing with the viewbox attribute now..it seems a little tricky!

Comment: so i want the containing div to be 200px by 200px ( and the svg to scale to fit the div) what values do i give the viewport?

Comment: @Vynce82 I am at office so can't answer anymore right now. but this link could help you to understand how viewport works. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

Comment: with "viewBox="0 0 600 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">"

Comment: i can't understand the behavior of viewbox...i'm just exporting the svg files at the size i think i'll be using them ( and using transparency to make it more subtle) but I would like to use these images with twitter bootstrap so that they scale. Would it be easier if i have an evenly divisible height & width?

Comment: I would like to scale uniformly to fill the containing div -- and then worry about resizing & styling through css on the container...i was in the middle of reading that article as you suggested it :) but it was confusing

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the `<svg>` element a viewBox attribute to stop that happening. Try viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" to begin and adjust as necessary.